# New user Registration & Authentication on Android app with django Backend

Tags: android, django, authentication

I wish to implement a registration (and then authentication) for a new user who uses my android app. A django based framework is sitting on the back-end.

The workflow is the same as any other app:

- User signs up.
- User logs in using the credentials. (or user may use FB/ Google login directly)
- User proceeds to main app.

From the backend, it is required for user to be authenticated(logged in) to use most of the functionality. Moreover, a decent level of security is also a requirement. From the django side, this task is fairly easy for HTML pages due to built in registration views and decorators. However, my question is how to implement this for android. I am in total fix regarding the workflow of the entire system.

From what I've searched on internet, people suggest two things as solution to this:

1. Develop on HTML and use android's webview for this entire thing.
2. Use POST request to send User ID & Passwd to backend. The workflow after that is unclear to me since I can't use django's inbuilt system with it (CSRF protection, auth etc.)

Now the problem is that I have not implemented any website for the application, and I am more comfortable doing it on mobile app. I have gone through numerous tutorials on auth, outh and REST packages of django, but all of them seem to be tailored for webapp.

My question is: What is the mot suitable flow considering app has to be for professional use ?

Comment: suggest you probably want Django REST Framework to provide a JSON API for the app and OAuth2 authentication http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_03.html

Comment: @Anentropic: Thanks for reply. Yes it seems that what is you say is the way out. But it doesn't explain to me the flow. Can you point me to any tutorial/ link that would explain the flow from client (Not web page) and server side, from registration to auth ?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=android%20oauth2%20client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build REST API for django signin/registration process.

One of the packages that can help you with that is https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using REST framework for Django with Token Authentication.

Comment: you have an example? I´m in the same situation as you

Comment: @KiokoKiaza Unfortunately, all my code is proprietary. I will tell you I followed REST framework to the word. I can help you if you create a question. Also, if you tell me exactly where you're stuck, I will add more details in the answer.

Comment: @silent_grave, I have my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646690/flutter-google-sign-in-authenticate-django-social-auth-for-google. Could you please guide me. I am completely lost.