# Flutter google sign in authenticate django social auth for google

Tags: django, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, django-socialauth

I am creating a flutter android app which uses google sign in. Once logged in, I recieve accesstoken and idtoken. I want to use this token to authenticate my backend which uses django social auth and

1. Login and return the authoken, if the user has already signed up, **or**
2. Register the user , login and return the user id and authtoken.

Is this possible ? If so please suggest any documents online or please explain how should I approach this.

Answer (score 3):

Over the years of doing this again and again, I found the solution below works well for me. It creates clear understanding of who is doing what.

Basically, you need:

1. Django Rest framework-backed token authentication for normal API requests. Mostly your app works on this. Link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication
2. Google or Facebook or any other login to issue an auth token in 1. Thus effectively FB/ Google shortcuts the process of typing in username and password.

This is achieved via the flow below:

1. New user comes in and signs in via FB/ Google
2. You get Fb/Google token and send it to your backend
3. You verify the validity of the token. Re-obtain user name and email from G/FB from the backend. Use these details to create a user account in your backend. DO NOT USE email provided from front-end for account creation (assuming email is your primary unique user identifier)

> NOTE: Don't forget to check if account already exists. If it does, this is a returning user/ login and not a new user. In this case, validate and return valid Django Rest Token

4. Once 3 is complete, issue a Django REST framework Token in response to the request made in 3.
5. After 4, you have a token in your app. Use this token for normal requests.

Happy coding! Happy to answer follow-up questions.

Comment: Thank you @silent_grave. I have been trying this approach. But the token access token I get from Android Google SignIn always throws error in Django. Its not able to identify the token.

Comment: Does the Client Id or API key needs to be same? How and where do I add it ?

Comment: @stackoverflowrohit What is the error you're getting?  What is the payload you're sending?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible,first you have to create your api using django Rest Framework,the link below can help you to create your backend and set a token for every user:

https://dev.to/amartyadev/flutter-app-authentication-with-django-backend-1-21cp

then you have to add social authentication to your backend,you can write it yourself or using link below to use library :

https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

after this approach you have to create your flutter app,the below link is a useful resource to connect your backend and your flutter app :

https://www.asapdevelopers.com/flutter-login-app-with-python-backend/

Comment: Thank you for the answe. This package has some issues. https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 and its not working. No response from the person who created it.